# When I am accessing the particular value in the array of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my array of JSON data. I want access the `UserID` field from array of JSON named as `jsonResult`.Please suggest me right solution for above JSON.

```
[ 
  {
    "UserRelationshipID":1,
    "SubordinateUserID":1014,
    "UserID":3,
    "UserRelationshipTypeID":1
  }
]
```

Comment: Please format the question properly and show us what you have already tried so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have array of objects, you can get the userid as shown below. Later you can either save the result in a variable or something else according to your need instead of consoling the result.

```js
var jsonResult = [ {"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":1014,"UserID":3,"UserRelationshipTyp‌​eID":1}, {"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":2537,"UserID":3,"UserRelationshipTyp‌​eID":1}, {"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":3,"UserID":4,"UserRelationshipTypeID‌​":1}, {"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":7,"UserID":4,"UserRelationshipTypeID‌​":1}, {"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":6,"UserID":2537,"UserRelationshipTyp‌​eID":1}, {"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":3,"UserID":2537,"UserRelationshipTyp‌​eID":1}]

for(var i=0; i<jsonResult.length; i++){
  console.log(jsonResult[i].UserID)
}
```

Comment: it throws error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I have shown you a working example. The error is because your json is not properly formatted and your formatting of the json has nothing to do with the question you asked.

Comment: @omkargandhi that means `jsonResult` is not an array. Please figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1):

**Your JSON Object**

```
var jsonResult = [{
  "UserRelationshipID":1,
  "SubordinateUserID":1014,
  "UserID":3,
  "UserRelationshipTypeID":1
},{
  "UserRelationshipID":2,
  "SubordinateUserID":1015,
  "UserID":4,
  "UserRelationshipTypeID":1
}];
```

**JavaScript**

```
for(var i=0;i<jsonResult.length;i++){
  console.log(jsonResult[i]);                    /*Access Object*/
  console.log("User ID" + jsonResult[i].UserID); /*Access Only UserID*/
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(jsonResult).each(function(Key,Value){
  console.log(Value);           /*Access Object*/
  console.log(Value.UserID);    /*Access Only UserID*/
});
```

Comment: Hey, btw the "JSON object" is not that. If it were, you'd need to parse it first.

Comment: Ahh! I see! I updated the comments @evolutionxbox Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
array().getJSONObject(0).get("UserID")
```

Comment: [
{"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":1014,"UserID":3,"UserRelationshipTypeID":1},
{"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":2537,"UserID":3,"UserRelationshipTypeID":1},
{"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":3,"UserID":4,"UserRelationshipTypeID":1},
{"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":7,"UserID":4,"UserRelationshipTypeID":1},
{"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":6,"UserID":2537,"UserRelationshipTypeID":1},
{"UserRelationshipID":1,"SubordinateUserID":3,"UserID":2537,"UserRelationshipTypeID":1},
How I am apply your code on above json.

Comment: I am use this solution but it not working it throws exception.
$.each(jsonResult[0], function (k, v) {
            jsonParse.push(v.UserID);
            console.log(jsonParse);
        });

Comment: No offence, but this isn't an answer, it's just a line of code.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects and an object inside it. You intend to do something with the `UserID` ield of the object inside the array. You can do it like this:

```
yourarray[0].UserID
```

where `yourarray` is your JSON, `0` is the index of the very first object and `UserID` is the `UserID` member of that object. If you want to iterate your array and access `UserID`, then

```
for (var index in yourarray) {
    //Do something with yourarray[index].UserID
}
```

More generally:

```
function iterateArray(arr, field) {
    for (var index in arr) {
        //Do something with arr[index][field]
    }
}
```

and call it like this: `iterateArray(yourarray, "UserID")`